# setting the value of a select element when generating HTML at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript that looks like this:

```
TheHTML = '<select>';
TheHTML = TheHTML + '<option value="1">first</option>'
TheHTML = TheHTML + '<option value="2">second</option>'
TheHTML = TheHTML + '</select>'
```

The HTML string is then add to the DOM with `$(selector).html(TheHTML);`

If I then want the second option to be selected, I need to add `$(selector).find(select).val(2);`

Is there a way to generate the HTML so that the select element has the second value selected when it's added to the DOM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `selected` attribute

```
TheHTML += '<option value="2" selected>second</option>'
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8g3N8/)

Answer (score 1):

```
TheHTML = '<select>';
TheHTML = TheHTML + '<option value="1">first</option>';
TheHTML = TheHTML + '<option value="2" selected>second</option>'; //notice the selected parameter
TheHTML = TheHTML + '</select>'
```

If your options are generated dynamically you can do as following:

```
var selected = 3;
TheHTML = '<select>';
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    TheHTML = TheHTML + '<option value="1" ' + ( i == selected ? 'selected' : '' ) + '>first</option>';
}
TheHTML = TheHTML + '</select>';
```

By the way the faster way of making the HTML is joining a array instead of appending to string:

```
TheHTML = [];
TheHTML.push('<select>');
TheHTML.push('<option value="1">first</option>');
TheHTML.push('<option value="2" selected>second</option>');
TheHTML.push('</select>');

TheHTML = TheHTML.join('');
```